# How do you write factorial in C?

Tags: c, math, factorial

I need to input this equation and there's a factorial in it. I would like to know if there was something like * = multiplication or pow(1,3) for factorial of something in C.

```
term = pow(-1, K) * pow(x, 2K)/(2K)
```

The factorial would be for the last 2K.

Comment: There is no built in standard function, you need to write your own factorial implementation.

Comment: Could you give me an indication on how I would be able to do that?

Comment: One way: Use a `for`loop from `1` to `2K` and divide term `term` by each number.

Comment: It is generally implemented as a recursive function. You can probably search `factorial` on this site and come up with a handful of examples.

Comment: Writing a factorial function is used as examples in just about all languages. A quick search in a search engine should give you thousands of results.

Comment: Factorials overflow standard integer types pretty quickly, so it is better to express term(k) by means of term(k - 1). That strategy should also get rid of the two calls to `pow`.

Comment: depending on how scientific your needs are I wonder if GSL would be worth using? https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/

Comment: If you are trying to approximate `cos(x)` using the series, then that's not the best way to go about it in C, neither for precision nor performance.

Comment: @dxiv that's exactly what I'm trying to do, could you give me more insight please? The way I did it above is sadly the only way I have understood how to do this problem so far and I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: Point is that you are after an end result in the [-1, 1] range, while both powers and factorials go up _very_ quickly. Calculating them is time consuming, and dividing them off loses precision. If @Joni's answer below is not sufficient (and @ M Oehm's for that matter), then you'll have to provide more details about the context and expectations.

Comment: Consider [Stirling's_approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation).

Answer (score 6):

Rarely you need a function for computing factorials. Factorials grow so fast that a look-up-table is sufficient for the few values for which the computation does not overflow. If you are computing terms in a loop, you can avoid computing the factorial using an accumulator for the entire term.

```
K = 0;
term = 1;

while (K<N) {

   /* use term */
   do_something_with(term);

   /* update term for new value of K */
   K += 1;
   term = -term * x*x / (2*K*(2*K-1));
}
```

If that seems unclear to you, you can first derive this program where the accumulators are explicit, and then combine the update step into a single variable like above. This program will still have problems with the factorial computation blowing up.

```
K = 0;
pow_minus_1_K = 1;
pow_x_2K = 1;
factorial_2K = 1;

while (K<N) {

   /* compute term */
   term = pow_minus_1_K * pow_x_2K/factorial_2K;

   /* update accumulators for new value of K */
   K += 1;
   pow_minus_1_K = -pow_minus_1_K;
   pow_x_2K *= x*x;
   factorial_2K *= 2*K*(2*K-1);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Factorials are easy to calculate, after all n! is just the product of all numbers up to n. But there is a practical problem: [Factorials overflow pretty quickly](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20151214-00/?p=92621). A 32-bit int can hold 12!, a 64-bit int 20!.

Depending on how your series converges, you might overflow the valid range.

With approximation series like yours, it is usually better to find a means to represent term k by means of term k − 1. In your case:

```
    term = pow(-1, k) * pow(x, 2*k) / fact(2*k)
```

you can represent a term as

```
    term[k + 1] = -term[k] * pow(x, 2) / ((2*k - 1) * (2*k - 2))
```

and your series becomes:

```
    double f(double x)
    {
        double term = 1.0;
        double res = term;
        int k = 0;

        while (k < 100) {
            double old = res;

            term = -term * (x / (2*k + 1)) * (x / (2*k + 2));
            res += term;

            if (res == old) break;
            k++;
        }

        return res;
    }
```

This function will use at most 100 iterations to calculate the cosine. It stops when the term doesn't contribute to the result. In practice, it reaches the result with about 10 iterations, so in that case the regular factorial calculations would have been accurate enough. Still, calculating them over and over is wasteful.

Answer (score 3):

There is no predefined function for factorial, but it can be recursively implemented as follows.

```
int factorial( int a )
{
    if ( 0 == a )
        return 1;
    else
        return a * factorial( a - 1 );
}
```

People who like the `?` operator might implement the function as follows.

```
int factorial( int a )
{
    return 0 == a ? 1 : ( a * factorial( a - 1 ) );
}
```

If a non-recursive formulation is desired, the implementation can be done as follows.

```
int factorial( int a )
{
    int Result = 1;
    for ( int i = a; i > 0; Result *= i, i-- );
    return Result;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If for some reason recursive functions leave you scratching your head, you can also implement it without recursion:

```
/* calculate n factorial */
unsigned long long nfact (int n)
{
    if (n <= 1) return 1;

    unsigned long long s = n;

    while (--n)
        s *= n;

    return s;
}
```

(**note:** it is up to you to you to implement a test for overflow, if desired)

Comment: I think, this can be further improved  if you put `if (n <= 1) return 1;` instead of `if (n <= 0) return 1;` after all, 1! = 1. Of course the `while` must be adjusted as well: `while(n-- > 1)`

Comment: You know, you were 100% right. Change made. Thank You!. Now it is in good shape `:)` Look closely at the `n--`, it's not quite `n--` it is `--n` which accounts for the reduction.

Comment: Ah, yes. You are right. I didn't notice the `s = n;` `:)` the right direction is as you say...

Answer (score 2):

I think using recursion for this problem is a good way to get started with recursion and understand the way it works, but it's not efficient enough since you're calling a function every time. If you want to know why, do a test and see how long it takes. Although I should say, the iterative method is not significantly better either.

From *Code Complete* by Steve McConnell:

> **Don't use recursion for factorials or Fibonacci numbers**
>
> One problem with computer-science textbooks is that they present silly
>   examples of recursion. The typical examples are computing a factorial
>   or computing a Fibonacci sequence. Recursion is a powerful tool, and
>   it's really dumb to use it in either of those cases. If a programmer
>   who worked for me used recursion to compute a factorial, I'd hire
>   someone else.

So when keep that in mind when going over the recursive versions that are posted here. Now, how to write one.

Basically you have a base case for when the number is less than 1, and a general recursive case. You generally have a base case and a recursive case in a recursive function. For a factorial, it would look something like this:

```
int factorial_rec(int number)
{
    if (number == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }else
    {
        return number * factorial_rec(number - 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
long fact(int num)
{
if(num==0)
    return 1;
else
    return num*fact(num-1);
}
```

Include the above code and call this method to get factorial of a number.

Answer (score 0):

The code to find factorial of a given number using recursive algorithm can be as shown below :

```
#include<stdio.h>
int fact(int n)
{
    if(!n)
        return 1;
    else
        return (n*fact(n-1));
}
void main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Enter number : ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("\nFactorial of %d is : %d",n,fact(n));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>  

long factorial(int n)  
{  
  if (n == 0)  
    return 1;  
  else  
    return(n * factorial(n-1));  
}  

void main()  
{  
  int number;  
  long fact;  
  printf("Enter a number: ");  
  scanf("%d", &number);   

  fact = factorial(number);  
  printf("Factorial of %d is %ld\n", number, fact);  
  return 0;  
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int n, i;
    unsigned long long fact = 1;
    printf("Enter an integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

// shows error if the user enters a negative integer
    if (n < 0)
        printf("Error! Factorial of a negative number doesn't exist.");
    else {
        for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
            fact *= i;
        }
        printf("Factorial of %d = %llu", n, fact);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>  
int main()    
{    
    int i,fact=1,number;    
    printf("Enter a number: ");    
    scanf("%d",&number);    
    for(i=1;i<=number;i++){    
        fact=fact*i;    
    }    
    printf("Factorial of %d is: %d",number,fact);      
    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).